# Woocommerce + PayPal: processing order even when cancelled

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm using woocomerce with PayPal and my orders are being processed successfully even though the user cancelled during the payment on PayPal site. Would you happen to know why when checking out an order with PayPal and canceling before paying would trigger and complete an order anyway?

Is there a place to manually define the cancelurl?

Comment: Order is not completed, it's merely created. It shows as pending, waiting for ipn to call back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When the user cancels on paypal, he get redirected back to the site and the Thank you page comes up with all the order information. The cart gets emptied he gets the order emails and he can see the order in the history.